# sharepoint Browser issue (Edge)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, spservices, browser-compatibility

SharePoint 2013,

Recently they have updated to Windows 10 from 7, with Edge as a default browser. All the custom client side javascript (Ex: Using SPServices to read list items from different webapp or connecting to http soap webservices) fails to load the resource error. This issue does not happen in ie in windows 7. Is there any authentication issue for cross domain in Edge Browser? Is there a work around.

Answer (score 0):

A quick work around could be to force the browser open with the previous version.

Sample tag to include in the master page or individual pages:

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer should still be available in Windows 10. The Microsoft Edge menu should have a 'Open with internet explorer' control

[image]

Alternatively just type "ie" into cortana search. You can set ie as the default browser

This question is broad and it's unclear what the issue is though so you'll have to check it still even works with IE, but testing in other modern browsers like chrome and firefox would be a good idea. New security control standards often break legacy code (or in SharePoint the browser blocks or patches XSS vulnerabilities) so you may have to stick with IE for it to work.